# How often do you commit when you use a version control system for your own LaTeX documents? Why?

Tags: best-practices, workflow, git, subversion

I'd like learn about your practices and why you commit the way you do. Whether the practice is just "good" or "better" than another one is of course debatable but this topic could be really helpful for others. One could learn a lot from it. :)

How often do commit when you use Git, SVN etc. for your own LaTeX documents? Why? Also, did you learn anything from it, or did it even influence your workflow when creating a document?

**edit**

As Jubobs points out, git and SVN might greatly differ. Personally, I do not have a clue about anything other than git, so... I don't know. I initially created this topic for the usage of git but cfr implied they are somewhat the same. Not sure about this.

Comment: @cfr Oh, no, sorry, just didn't think broadly enough. Edited the op. Feel free to finetune the terms.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought you must have something git-specific in mind but couldn't figure out what!

Comment: I think the question has value, but it should be restricted to one VCS in particular; otherwise, it might be too broad. For instance, an SVN workflow is likely to greatly differ from a Git workflow. Also, you should specify whether you have collaboration in mind or whether you use version control only locally.

Comment: @Jubobs really? Personally, I do not have a clue about anything other than git, so... I don't know. I initially created this topic for the usage of git but cfr implied they are somewhat the same. Not sure about this. Also, cfr does not tell which software she uses so I think it still works. But actually I can't say because of the lack of experience. Could gladly restrict it to git!

Comment: @Jubobs I now restricted it to one's own document, i.e. not multiple authors. I do not agree about mentioning whether one saves locally only or has a remote repo. I say when you need the files on another machine pushing the content comes into play, otherwise... not. So this is just about the commits. Or maybe it's my *relative* inexperience speaking again but that is how I figured it. :)

Comment: I find a major difference between SVN and git (when not pushing to a collaborative repo), is that git allows rebasing: you can easily make lots of small commits and later reorder and "squash" them into logical units.

Comment: @eldering I am aware of there are probably a huge amount of differences between (these) two programs. Please, what do you use, how do you commit, and why? :) You could also write a note or two that your workflows between the two programs differ. That could actually be really interesting for others.

Comment: I originally asked whether it was specific to `git` because the question *seemed* to apply to my usage of `svn` and I wasn't clear why that was not relevant. However, I don't use `git` so maybe there are differences I'm not aware of. I find it hard to believe that many of the reasons to commit won't be common, though, since there are common reasons to use any version control system. I often make lots of small commits and, although I haven't yet made use of them, there are ways to rejig the repo afterwards, although some are only available with newer versions of `subversion`.

Comment: Moreover, I think that whether to commit or not should be dictated by workflow needs rather than the tool you are using to manage versions. If that isn't working well, it is a sign that you need to change the tool. At least, if that's an option. Changing when you commit in light of the tool you use should be an option of last resort IMHO. This is partly why I tried to give a tool-agnostic answer. If my reasons are good, they are good reasons for me to find a tool which fits that workflow. If not, then the tool is irrelevant.

Comment: BTW: I voted to close the question since, to me, most of _How often_ questions are totally sensitive to users habits. One is comfortable to commit every two minutes, another every day. And both cases are fine.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino This topic was about someone saying "I did X and Y and here is why: ABC." The application of the broad "opinion-based" closing reason is, in this case, more of a lean to stifle the display of different experiences which could be helpful. Out of principle.

Comment: @henry: I see your point. However, I'm not gonna ask "Which is the best way to draw this or that?" because, very similarly to this question, is, to me, opinion-based. And this is just to explain the closing reason. :)

Comment: I think, this is not a LaTeX related question, since the committing interval does not depend on LaTeX.

Answer (score 15):

I generally commit in the following cases:

- I am switching to work on another document, especially one which is part of a different project.
- I am finishing for the day, taking a break or may be changing computers.
- I am about to run a system update on my laptop (which runs Arch and is therefore theoretically more vulnerable to unexpected breakage although that doesn't seem true in practice).
- I am stuck.
- I find myself worrying about changing things in case I lose them and change my mind.
- I want to send a copy of my current work to somebody else.
- I am about to print a copy and the document itself includes mark-up noting the revision information.
- I want to clean up files I no longer need, including generated files or old stuff. (This is in case I accidentally `rm` my current work.)
- I want to move, rename, split or copy files.
- I'm about to try something which could go really wrong (especially with graphics) and I want a known-good point to revert to.

My commit messages leave a great deal to be desired, though, and I'd love to know how to make these more useful.

Revision control makes my code cleaner. I still tend to initially comment stuff out but every now and again I go through and delete to reduce clutter. I know the information is in the repo so I don't really need to put up with the mess.

Branching and tagging are *starting* to change my workflow but I have probably not yet figured out how to maximise their usefulness.

One of my projects takes a really long time to commit or update and that is quite annoying. (It is worse on my laptop for some reason.)

I have been greatly relieved to discover how easy it is to go back and reinstate earlier versions of bits of a document when I realise that I really ought not to have changed X to Y because Y is clearly more misguided than X!

I'm not sure this is a very helpful answer...

Comment: I think these are all good reasons, especially to commit all work before sending it to someone or e.g. submitting a paper: then you can optionally tag it and recover the exact version you sent.

Comment: @eldering Yes. I've started tagging submissions. For sending to people as drafts, I tend to just make a note in the commit message since the version is on the PDF I send them in that case. (Obviously this only goes for people reading it as a draft/work-in-progress.)