# What are the "best practices" when writing a thesis in Latex?

Tags: best-practices, thesis

I am starting to write my master thesis in latex. So far I have only written article-like texts, so this is my first big document.

I would like to start with some good general good practices. Specially since I might go into academia and pursue a PhD.

What are good principles to keep in mind?. For example, do you have one single huge tex file, or do you have several smaller files for each chapter?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9931/headings-and-advice-to-write-a-phd-in-physics-using-latex?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163616/how-do-you-organize-the-files-for-your-latex-documents

Comment: Maybe loosely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201164/how-often-do-you-commit-when-you-use-a-version-control-system-for-your-own-latex

Comment: From the top of my head.... Use a good class template. Use top-down writing. Use environments and special-purpose commands for adding markup. Don't use add-hoc markup. When using TikZ, use styles. Use comments. Write your bibliography with `biblatex` (my choice). Use `booktabs` and or `pdfplotstable`when typesetting tables. Use `pgfplots` when typesetting data plots. Use `siunitx` when typesetting SI units....

Comment: @MartinSchroeder It would help if yous could tell the OP where the question has been answered before.